# Validate a comment from a custom module

Tags: 7, comments

I want to validate comments using a custom module; I am using `hook_comment()`, and "validate" as value for `$op`, but I cannot get the value of the comment field. How do I get the comment value from a custom module?

Comment: Provide some code. The form values of the comment editing form should be in the first argument to your implementation of `hook_comment`.

Comment: thanks kiamlaluno for take time to edit my question. Also, thanks Oswald, I take note of your suggestion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming you're working in Drupal 6:

```
/**
 * Implementation of hook_comment().
 */
function mymodule_comment(&$a1, $op) {
  switch ($op) {
    case 'validate':
      $subject = $a1['subject'];
      $comment = $a1['comment'];
      // validate here
      break;
  }
}
```

In Drupal 7 hook_comment() is gone, being replaced by a set of hooks hook_comment_view(), hook_comment_load(), etc. Unfortunately there is no hook_comment_validate() but see [this answer](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/6165/why-doesnt-the-comment-validation-work-under-drupal-7/6167#6167) for a solution.

Comment: yes, you are right! thanks for take time to answer my question!